# How to init a UIViewController whose Nib is the Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the following `UIViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var dayDatasource : DayDatasource;

    init(){
        self.dayDatasource = DayDatasource();
        super.init(nibName:nil, bundle: nil);
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.dayDatasource = DayDatasource();
        super.init(nibName:nil, bundle: nil);
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
    }
}
```

Now because I declare the `dayDatasource` property, swift forces me to create `init` methods. When I create the `init` methods it then complains that I need to call the designated `init` method for `UIViewController`. After googling, apparently the designated `init method is:

```
super.init(nibName:nil, bundle: nil);
```

When I use this however, I get a back screen. If I try the following:

```
super.init(nibName:"ViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle());
```

I get the following error:

> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle'

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: how are you instantiating your view controller?

Comment: The ViewController class the the file owner to the viewController in the main story board. I've never had to instantiate my view controllers in the past when using the story board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using storyboard segues for navigation, you should make `dayDatasource` an optional or forced unwrapped optional with a `?` or `!`. That will prevent requiring you to create the unused init method.

Then, in the view controller you are navigating from, override the `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function and set the `dayDatasource` variable.

On the other hand, if this is the first view controller being displayed, or you always want a new instance of `dayDatasource`, just create the instance in your variable declaration and the custom init will no longer be required.

```
var dayDatasource = DayDatasource()
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for the answer, by using var dayDatasource = DayDatasource()? it didnt require the init methods. With this said, I feel like this is a hack  perhaps? Is this they way it is supposed to be done? Or is this a Swift thing? In objective c these issues were never faced.

Comment: No, initializing variables this way is not a hack. You can even add the `lazy` keyword to postpone its initialization.

Answer (score 0):

you should write this:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)   {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

without passing `nibName` to nil or hardcoded.

*Let me know in the comments if this fixes your problem*